# Lodash version number is mismatch in package-lock.json?

Tags: reactjs, npm, lodash, veracode

i am using the lodash latest version. But in package-lock.json. It's in version @4.17.4. Because of this veracode is showing high risk vulnerability in lodash. When i ran npm audit.

```
Invalid: lock file's lodash@4.17.4 does not satisfy lodash@4.17.15
```

it shows like this.

After giving npm audit fix. Its still in the same version number in package-lock.json.

Is there any way to update the version number in package-lock.json.

Please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried `npm i`, `npm update` or removing package-lock.json and run `npm i` or `npm ci` ?